# Errors when opening the project

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

This is the cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "uep_magicstats2023"
version = "0.0.4"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
dotenvy = "0.15.7"
text-colorizer = "1.0.0"
rustc_version = "0.4.0"
unix-time = "0.1.5"
md5 = "0.7.0"
regex = { version = "1.8.3" }
mysql = { version = "24.0.0" }

[[bin]]
name = "uep_magicstats2023"
path = "src/magicstats2023.rs"
```

And these are the errors displayed when lib.rs opens as the project is opened using Intelli IDEA (jetbrains)

https://paste.opensuse.org/pastes/2e6087f04700

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

I posted everywhere so I had to track back the prints to fall back on this post lol ^^

To resolve the issue I did, on the folder where the .toml file is located:

- cargo update
- cargo check

...and everywhere I did those (maybe cargo check alone is sufficient) I never seen lib.rs opening again !!